# Size of the image does not increase beyond the limit by inline styling?

Tags: html, css, image, styling

```
<div class="container no padding">
    <div class= "row small-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg 8 top-post-left">
           <div class ="feature-image-thumb relative">
               <div class="overlay overlay-big"></div>
               <img class="img-fluid" src="img/cover_png" style= "width:900px;height:400px;">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to increase the size of the image but it doesn't not increase beyond 400 to 500 px the section of the image includes various classes of css, bootstrap, j query,. I'm not able to find which class is putting size constraint on the image I want to increase it's size to full screen.

Comment: please share your code with the community so we can help you furthermore

Comment: A good place to start will be: 1) Sharing the html with surronding div(s) and 2) the explictilty listed style classes.

Comment: applied inline styling doesn't work which is the problem I referred

Comment: the img-fluid set the max-size to 100%.... [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#responsive-images)

Comment: Img-fluid is already set to 100% but still not working